# Is a COVID-19 antiviral such as Paxlovid available in Costa Rica?

Tags: covid-19, costa-rica

Is a COVID-19 antiviral such as Paxlovid readily available in Costa Rica?  I'm planning a trip there and I want to know if I can access it if I were to contract COVID-19.

Is there a website that tracks antiviral adoption in different parts of the world?

Comment: Over the counter, or on prescription/in hospital?

Answer (score 1):

No. The outgoing administration of Costa Rica did succeed in approving Paxlovid for import by private pharmacies but no private pharmacies have it.  My guess is that Paxlovid just isn't for sale yet on the private market, so unless your government tries to get it, you won't have it.

Panama has it, however, so people might want to go there instead of Costa Rica.

As for a list of the countries that have Paxlovid, I would imagine that the WHO, Pfizer, and some other outfits have a list, but I haven't been able to find one.